# How to exclude defer js extension in special page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

How to exclude extension in special page?

like it don't loading to onestep checkout page.
Because i'm using defer js extension no admin backend just auto enable but it affect onestep checkout page.

i just want to exclude checkout page.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getResponse();
        $htmlContent = $response->getBody();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your overall code will look like below:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $response = $observer->getEvent()->getResponse();
    $htmlContent = $response->getBody();
    $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
    $fullActionName = $request->getFullActionName();
    if ($fullActionName == 'checkout_index_index') {
        $response->setBody($htmlContent);
    }
    else
    {
    if (stripos($htmlContent, '<!DOCTYPE html') !== false) {
        $headers = $response->getHeaders()->toArray();
        if (array_key_exists('Content-Type', $headers)
            && $headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json'
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        $htmlContent = $this->moveJavascriptToFooter($htmlContent);

        // Set the body with the new HTML content
        $response->setBody($htmlContent);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: @niceonelee, check updated answer please.

Comment: @niceonelee , please check this value in your admin :https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-rediect-to-customer-dashboard-after-loggin-in-magento-2.html

Comment: @niceonelee , is it working for you?

Comment: thanks your helpful it is wokring